# Html.Kendo().Upload() dynamically enable or disable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I need find a way to dynamically enable or disable a Kendo upload:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Enable(false)
        .Name("attachments_" + item.QuestionId)
        .ShowFileList(true)
            .TemplateId("fileTemplate")
        .Async(a => a
             .Save("SaveAttachment", "Attachment", new { evaluationId = ViewBag.EvaluationId, questionId = item.QuestionId })
             .Remove("RemoveAttachment", "Attachment", new { evaluationId = ViewBag.EvaluationId, questionId = item.QuestionId })
             .AutoUpload(true)
        )
        .Files(files =>
        {
            if ((IList<dynamic>)ViewData["Attachment_" + item.QuestionId] != null)
            {
                foreach (var f in (IList<dynamic>)ViewData["Attachment_" + item.QuestionId])
                {
                    files.Add().Name(f.Name).Extension(f.Extension).Size(f.Size);
                }
            }
        })
)
```

How can I do that?

I tried setting .Enable to:

```
.Enable(bool.Parse(ViewBag.AllowEdit))
```

And it threw an error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request.          Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Source Error:

Line 95:             .ShowFileList(true)
Line 96:                 .TemplateId("fileTemplate")
Line 97:             .Async(a => a
Line 98:                  .Save("SaveAttachment", "Attachment", new { evaluationId = ViewBag.EvaluationId, questionId = item.QuestionId })
Line 99:                  .Remove("RemoveAttachment", "Attachment", new { evaluationId = ViewBag.EvaluationId, questionId = item.QuestionId })

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast that ViewBag variable first.

.Enable(bool.Parse((string)ViewBag.AllowEdit))

Answer (score 1):

One thing to be aware of with Kendo upload control is that even when it is disabled users can still drag and drop files on to it. There is a way to always have drag and drop disabled: [kendo forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/disable-drag-drop#2293863)

I did not try that workaround since I want to allow it when the control is enabled.